# Word for fear of one's own cuts

Tags: word-request, terminology

When I cut myself, I have a panic attack, and I believe that I have a phobia of it. Is there a name of a phobia where I have a fear of my own cuts?

Other people's cuts and blood do not have the same effect on me, it is just my own. I don't have aichmophobia (a fear of sharp objects)

I do not have a fear of blood, so it's not haemophobia.

Injections are fine, I've had loads.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to be a bit creative with the title! ;)

Comment: It's totally fine to be creative but I assume(not sure) that the title of a question is used by search engines to map the data on the question's page. One would only search **I'm scared of my own cuts** if they want to know about the fear and about overcoming it but they're more likely to type **Word for fear of one's own cuts** on Google if they're interested in the name of fear rather that the fear itself. I edited the title just so it could benefit everyone else who'd Google it in future. Hope you don't mind. :-)

Comment: @7_R3X, It's fine, I don't mind at all

Comment: How about Traumaphobia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traumatophobia

Comment: @RonJensen Why not post that as an answer? Also, its traumatophobia, not traumaphobia.

Comment: Sounds like a special sub-case of ***Fear of needles,*** [known in the medical literature as ***needle phobia***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_needles). They both involve breaching the outer perimeter of the body (the ***skin***). I kinda doubt this particular sub-case has a more specialized medical name, and I can't see that ordinary people would need ever such a word. Only people with severe psychological problems actually *like* cutting themselves or being cut.

Comment: Other phobias are Algophobia (fear of pain), Amychophobia (fear of being scratched). I don't think what you have would be characterised as a *phobia* since with most phobias one's reaction would occur **before** or **in anticipation** of an event. Freezing after the event might be a form of **shock**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Injections are fine, I've had loads

Comment: Do you mean that you have a fear of *being cut*, regardless of who is doing the cutting? You said "when I cut myself", but I would guess that the idea of having someone else cut you bothers you too. Aichmophobia is a fairly general term that encompasses a range of more specific fears: some sufferers are afraid of cutting themselves, while other sufferers are afraid of accidentally cutting others - or the fear may be specific to certain types of sharp things. So you could probably say that your fear of being cut falls within the spectrum of Aichmophobia.

Comment: @nnnnnn I have a fear of the actual cut itself, as when I get cut I'm fine, it's a few minutes after when I see the cut itself

Comment: Molysmophobia?  Is it possible you're afraid of the cut becoming infected?

Answer (score 2):

According to *Campell's Psychiatric Dictionary*, which I have here in hardcopy, the closest match is **traumatophobia** which means a fear of injuries, but is not specifically fear of injury to one's self.  (It offers **belonophobia** as a fear of sharp objects, if that pertains.)

All that said, please be aware that, excepting agoraphobia, these *–phobia* constructions are considered archaic in modern psychiatry.  If you were to present for treatment of this condition, you would be diagnosed as having **Specific phobia, fear of injury** as per the ICD-10-CM (US), code F40.233, or **Specific phobia, blood-injection-injury** as per the DSM5, code 300.28.

I have no idea why agoraphobia is still called agoraphobia.